# fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation always returns NULL

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

i implemented the method used in Lib android [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current?hl=pt_br), see:

```
  fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null) {
                    localidade = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Local correto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Localidade vazia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

However, within OnSuccess the result is ALWAYS null, I am testing on my mobile (9.0 android) with LOCAL(gps) mode on and still returns null, my manisfest has the necessary permissions: `<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION "/>`

In my view nothing is wrong, so why ALWAYS null?

Answer (score 1):

Last known location is registered known location by the user. If you read on the location page it states that last known location can be null in certain situations; in those scenarios it is advised you request location updates. Following is taken from the page:

> The location object can be nullin the following situations:
>
> Location is disabled in the device settings. The result may nulleven
>   be that the last location was retrieved earlier, because disabling the
>   location also clears the cache. The device never recorded its own
>   location, which happens when the device is new or when it has been
>   restored to factory settings. The Google Play Services platform on the
>   device has been restarted and no active Fused Location Provider API
>   clients have requested location after services have been restarted. To
>   avoid this situation, create a new customer and request location
>   updates.